# How to populate a text box inside a gridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, populate

I have one gridview that contains a textbox in row 0 column 0.

My question is, how can I populate my TextBox in row 0 in column 0from my vb.net code behind to display  the letter "A" in my textbox.

I am using this instruction, but my TextBox Disapear.

```
gridview.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text ="A"
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, Please add the whole loop, and describe it further more

Comment: ok forget the loop, I have a gridview, my gridview contais a textbox in the row 0, how can I send from my code behind a letter "a" to my textbox inside the gridview in the row 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gridview.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text ="A"` will place the letter "A" in the same rendered `td` as the TextBox.

You need to find the the specific `TextBox` control you want to populate.

If the gridview is DataBound then you can do this in the GridView's `DataBound` event. <s>or if it's not Databound then you can use the `Page.PreRenderComplete` event.</s> *There must be some form of backing data or the gridview will not render any data rows which will contain a TextBox (or did you place the textbox in a Header or footer?)*

But in either case you need to find the TextBox control within a specific row.  In your question you are looking in Row 1 so you would need to do this:

```
    Dim row as GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(0)
    Dim tbx as TextBox = row.FindControl("TextBox1")
    If tbx isnot nothing then tbx.Text = "A"
```